# how to add custom page layout pages magento

Tags: magento

I have custom layout page

I have added the following code to  app/code/core/Mega/page/etc/config.xml

```
<shop_overview module="page" translate="label">
    <label>Shop OverView Page</label>
    <template>page/shop_overview.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>shop_overview</layout_handle>
</shop_overview>
```

This show the "Shop Over View Page" on admin panel in page layout drop-down

I want to remove product list from category for this page layout only.
I tried the following but it is not working.

```
<shop_overview translate="label">
  <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/shop_overview.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="category.products">
    <remove name="product_list" />
  </reference>
</shop_overview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can assign static block to this category by changing display mode to `Static Block Only`.

And then creating and selecting that block for that category.

Reference Link: http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials/19-how-add-static-block-category-page